# Repeat regression with varying dependent variable

Tags: r, loops, regression, dplyr

I've searched both Stack and google for a solution, none found to solve my problem.

I have about 40 dependent variables, for which I aim to obtain adjusted means (lsmeans). I need adjusted means for group A and group B, after accounting for some covariates. My final object should be a data frame with predicted means for all 40 dependent variables for group A and group B.

This is what I tried, without any success:

```
# Examplified here with 2 outcome variables
outcome1 <- c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16)
outcome2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
var1 <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b")
var2 <- c(10, 11, 12, 9, 14, 9, 5, 8)
var3 <- c(100, 101, 120, 90, 140, 90, 50, 80)

df <- data.frame(outcome1, outcome2, var1, var2, var3)

dependents <- c(outcome1, outcome2)

library(lsmeans) #install.packages("lsmeans")

results <- list()
for (i in seq_along(dependents) {
    fit <- lm(i ~ var1 + var2 + var3, data= df)
    summary <- summary(lsmeans(fit, "var1"))
    summary$outcome <- i
    results[i] <- summary
    }
```

Comment: You have a missing parentheses `for(i in seq_along(dependents))`, also `results[i]` could be `results[[i]]` and  `lm(i~` is not correct

Comment: Try `lapply(dependents, function(x) {fit <- lm(paste(x,'~', 'var1+var2+var3'), data=df);summary(lsmeans(fit, 'var1', data=df));})` where `dependents <- c('outcome1', 'outcome2')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few typos and things, but I think this is what you want:

```
# Examplified here with 2 outcome variables
outcome1 <- c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16)
outcome2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
var1 <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b")
var2 <- c(10, 11, 12, 9, 14, 9, 5, 8)
var3 <- c(100, 101, 120, 90, 140, 90, 50, 80)

df <- data.frame(outcome1, outcome2, var1, var2, var3)

dependents <- c("outcome1", "outcome2")

library(lsmeans) #install.packages("lsmeans")

results <- list()
for (i in seq_along(dependents)) {
  eq <- paste(dependents[i],"~ var1 + var2 + var3")
  fit <- lm(as.formula(eq), data= df)
  summary <- summary(lsmeans(fit, "var1"))
  summary$outcome <- i
  results[[i]] <- summary
}
```

Comment: Edited, didn't need the new column names after I changed to a character formula.

Comment: perhaps the "summary$outcome <- i" should be "summary$outcome <- dependents[i]", which made it work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option using `lapply`.

```
dependents <- c('outcome1', 'outcome2')
lst <- lapply(dependents, function(x) {
         fit <- lm(paste(x,'~', 'var1+var2+var3'), data=df)
         summary(lsmeans(fit, 'var1', data=df))})
Map(cbind, lst, outcome = seq_along(dependents))
```

Comment: I'm not lucky enough to get the apply-family going yet. This one was nice but did not return the outcome name in the list. But I'm very grateful for your help, it did most of the work.

Comment: @AdamRobinsson  I didn't notice that.  Updated with a possible option

Answer (score 1):

In more modern R, [the **lazyeval** package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lazyeval/versions/0.2.2) provides better functions for working with formulas.

Here's my version of your code:

```
#load libs
library(tidyverse)
library(lazyeval)
library(lsmeans)

#make data
df = tibble(
  y1 = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16),
  y2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
  var1 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"),
  var2 = c(10, 11, 12, 9, 14, 9, 5, 8),
  var3 = c(100, 101, 120, 90, 140, 90, 50, 80)
)

#outcomes
outcomes = c("y1", "y2")

#fit
results <- list()
for (i in seq_along(outcomes)) {
  #make a formula
  f = i ~ var1 + var2 + var3
  
  #set outcome, must be a symbol explicitly
  f_lhs(f) = as.symbol(outcomes[i])
  
  #fit
  fit <- lm(f, data = df)
  
  #save
  summary <- summary(lsmeans(fit, "var1"))
  results[[i]] = summary
}

#set outcome names
names(results) = outcomes

#print results
results
```

The last line prints:

```
$y1
 var1 lsmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 a       5.5 1.38  4     1.68     9.32
 b      12.5 1.38  4     8.68    16.32

Confidence level used: 0.95 

$y2
 var1 lsmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 a      2.75 0.688  4     0.84     4.66
 b      6.25 0.688  4     4.34     8.16

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Generally, it would be easier to work with strings, and convert to a formula just before fitting. Here I did it using formulas.