# R Multiple Regression Loop and Extract Coefficients

Tags: r, for-loop, extract, coefficients, multiple-regression

I have to perform multiple linear regression for many vectors of dependent variables on the same matrix of independent variables.

For example, I want to create 3 models such that:

```
lm( d ~ a + b + c )
lm( e ~ a + b + c )
lm( f ~ a + b + c )
```

from the following matrix (a,b,c are the independent variables and d,e,f are the dependent variables)

```
       [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]
[1,]    a1       b1       c1       d1       e1       f1
[2,]    a2       b2       c2       d2       e2       f2
[3,]    a3       b3       c3       d3       e3       f3
```

I then want to store the coefficients from the regression in another matrix (I have reduced the number of columns and vectors in my example for ease of explanation).

Comment: Please show an example that is [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  Also, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377737/repeat-regression-with-varying-dependent-variable)

Comment: Sorry, I am a first time user. The link looks to be similar to what I am trying to do. Thanks

Comment: How is that other matrix suppose to look? There are no coefficients for the dependent variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method that is not very general, but will work if you substitute your own dependent variable names in `depvar`, and of course the independent variables common to all models in the inner `lm()` call, and of course the dataset name.  Here I have demonstrated on `mtcars`, a built-in dataset supplied with R.

```
depvar <- c("mpg", "disp", "qsec")
regresults <- lapply(depvar, function(dv) {
    tmplm <- lm(get(dv) ~ cyl + hp + wt, data = mtcars)
    coef(tmplm)
})
# returns a list, where each element is a vector of coefficients
# do.call(rbind, ) will paste them together
allresults <- data.frame(depvar = depvar, 
                         do.call(rbind, regresults))
# tidy up name of intercept variable
names(allresults)[2] <- "intercept"
allresults
##   depvar  intercept        cyl          hp        wt
## 1    mpg   38.75179 -0.9416168 -0.01803810 -3.166973
## 2   disp -179.04186 30.3212049  0.21555502 59.222023
## 3   qsec   19.76879 -0.5825700 -0.01881199  1.381334
```

**Edit** based on suggestion by @Mike Wise:

If you want only a numeric dataset but want to keep the identifier, you can add it as a row.name, like this:

```
allresults <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, regresults),
                         row.names = depvar)
# tidy up name of intercept variable
names(allresults)[1] <- "intercept"
allresults
##       intercept        cyl          hp        wt
## mpg    38.75179 -0.9416168 -0.01803810 -3.166973
## disp -179.04186 30.3212049  0.21555502 59.222023
## qsec   19.76879 -0.5825700 -0.01881199  1.381334
```

Comment: This seems to me to be what he meant. I think the question needs to be editied and remove the dependent variable columns for this answer to match the question though.

Comment: Thanks you are right - I added an alternative that returns a data.frame consisting only of coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

I actually recently encountered the same issue and a quick and easy way to go about it is to simply manually add all the results to a dataframe with the coefficients function.

`coeffdf <- data.frame(coefficients(lm1),coefficients(lm2))`

It will work well if you have the same variables for each regression.